# Add an event on the radio button

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to apply an event on my radio buttons when I click on it...

I tried with the following code: [my code](http://jsfiddle.net/DhCeB/)

```
<div id="inline_content">
<form class="type" >
    <header class="ui-header">
        <h2 class="ui-title">Duration</h2>
    </header>
<div class="ui-content">
        <ul class="ui-listview">
            <li class="li-has-radio">
                <label>
                    15 mn
                    <input type="radio" value="15" name="radSize" checked="checked"/>
                </label>
            </li>
            <li class="li-has-radio">
                <label>
                    30 mn
                    <input type="radio" value="30" name="radSize"/>
                </label>
            </li>
            <li class="li-has-radio">
                <label>
                    45 mn
                    <input type="radio" value="45" name="radSize"/>
                </label>
            </li>

        </ul>
    </div>
</form>
</div>
```

And the javascript:

```
$("#inline_content input[name='type']").click(function(){
alert('You clicked radio!');
// if($('input:radio[name=type]:checked').val() == "walk_in"){
    alert($('input:radio[name=type]:checked').val());
    //$('#select-table > .roomNumber').attr('enabled',false);
//}
});
```

But it doesn't seem work!

Thanks in advance.

Comment: are you doing this in a dom radio state? i dont see any inputs named type.

Comment: you are using wrong selector:http://jsfiddle.net/ehsansajjad465/DhCeB/1/

Comment: in addition to Daniels Comment, you should use jquerys `.change()` function

Answer (score 3):

Some problems:

- You didn't include jQuery in the fiddle, so `$` is undefined.
- You don't have any `input` named `type`
- You should listen to `change` event instead of `click` one, because inputs can be changed in other ways, e.g. using the keyboard.

This works (if you have jQuery):

```
$("#inline_content input[name='radSize']").on('change', function(){
    alert('You clicked radio!');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Change the selector, see [jquery api](http://api.jquery.com/radio-selector/)

```js
$("#inline_content input:radio").click(function(){
    //do something
});
```

your code: [**jsfiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/x3HUc/)

Answer (score 0):

Here is a jQuery-free version:

```
var input = document.querySelectorAll("input[name='radSize']");
var totalInputs = input.length;
var radioClick = function(){
    console.log(this.value);
}
for ( i = 0; i < totalInputs; i++ ) {
    input[i].addEventListener('change', radioClick, 0);
}
```